# Get users registered 30 days ago(or more)

Tags: multisite, users

How(in wordpress multisite) can i get id of users, who signed up 30 days ago, or more? I am building free trial system for 30 days. I want to have a function, that check when user signed up, and how many days have passed. The function should return number of days that passed.

It's easy to get user signed up time:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->user_registered;
```

It's echo:

```
2012-09-16 6:25:47
```

Now, how to check how many days passed from above time?

Answer (score 5):

There's the function [`human_time_diff( $from, $to );`](http://queryposts.com/function/human_time_diff/), which will compare two UNIX timestamps. Just use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) on `$GLOBALS['current_user']->user_registered;` and compare it with the current UNIX time.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it more systematically using a script you could do something like this

```
$timestamp_start = strtotime($startdate);
$timestamp_end = strtotime($enddate);
$difference = abs($timestamp_end - $timestamp_start);
```

Then have you can write a script that will check if it's been greater than 30 days

```
if ($difference >= 2592000){
//send invite code
}
```

You can also get a rounded version of just the days by doing this

```
$days = floor($difference/(60*60*24));
echo 'Days '.$days;
```

[Source](http://www.phpbook.net/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your answer, I combine your solutions, and it works!

human_time_diff, does not fit to my script, becouse it's return minutes, houers, and days with "ago" word. So, i create my own function that return only days without "ago".

Function code:

```
function count_days($from){

    $start_time = $from;
    $current_time = time();

    //convert given date to the unix time (in seconds)
    $unix_start_time = date("U",strtotime($start_time));

    //count the difference between current time and given date
    $diff = (int) abs($current_time - $unix_start_time);

    //Now, we change seconds for days
    if ($diff >= 86400) {
        $days = round($diff / 86400);
        if ($days <= 1) $days = 1;  
    }

    //returns days
    return $days;
}
```

First parametr of function is date, for example 22-09-2012. Next, this date is converted to unix seconds, and then we can subtract current time from this date. This way, we can calculate the days that have passed since a given date. Yay!

Thanks again!

Comment: `human_time_diff` doesn't append the word 'ago'...

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, it's my mistake. But anyway, human_time_diff, can return number of minutes, or hours. I want only get the number of days. Also my time format is 'd-m-Y', so i need to convert time to unix seconds.